# Display object data in array or list

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working with IONIC, I'm reading data from Service Rest and I wanna to display this data in the home page but every time I get a string, any one can help me in this.

**home.ts**

```
  AfficherT(){
    var url='http://localhost:8888/ticketF';
    console.log("Clickeed");
    this.result = this.http.get(url)
    this.result.subscribe(data => {
      this.chaine=JSON.stringify(data);
    });
  }
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-list>
  {{chaine}}
</ion-list>
```

[image: the result]

Comment: How do you want to display this data?

Comment: in a list or an array that will be better than a string

Comment: Remove the `JSON.stringify(...)`. After which you can access *any* property of your json. For eg: `{{ data.ticket }}`, etc

Comment: it give me [Object] [Object]

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `JSON.stringify`.

You convert your JS object to string so angular will display a string in template.

What you wan to use is `JSON.parse()` but you should not have do do this because `httpClient` already do this.

```
AfficherT(){
    var url='http://localhost:8888/ticketF';
    console.log("Clickeed");
    this.result = this.http.get<any[]>(url)
    this.result.subscribe(data => {
      this.chaine= data
    });
}
```

Comment: i try it but it give me [object] [object], also i create => 
ticketList:[]; this.ticketList=data; that give me an error Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: Try to type your reponse when using `this.http.get` = > `this.http.get<any[]>`` (Prefer a specific type than any)

Comment: nothing change it is always the same [Object][Object],and Error in the other one

Comment: When you are developping on angular i suggest you to use the chrome browser when you face some trouble, the error in chrome development tool is far more explicit.  you can try to remplace data with (data:any) => {this.chaine =(data)} and put a console log on this.chaine to check if it's an object.

Comment: But where are you seeing `[object Object]` ? in console or template ?

Comment: i'm seeing it in the home.html, the same result

Comment: Okkkk ! So it is normal ;) Angular doesn't know how display your object in template. You could print it using `json` pipe : `{{chaine | json}}`

Comment: it gives me the same result as a String, is that normal!!

Comment: What are you expecting see ? If you want to display object content you need to do it for each properties you want to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.stringify({"id":1,"name":"reza"});

```
AfficherT(){
    var url='http://localhost:8888/ticketF';
    console.log("Clickeed");
    this.result = this.http.get(url)
    this.result.subscribe(data => {
      this.chaine= JSON.stringify(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand !! it is the same thing !!